# Help with fadeout/fadein for four divs in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have four `div` elements that are under a parent `div`. These `div`s are filled with data that were in a PHP file. I got the data through the jQuery's `.getJSON()`. Anyways, I need to `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` these divs in a certain order. Here is what I have.

```
$("#images #image1").fadeOut(2000); //do this first
$("#images #image2").fadeIn(2000); 
$("#images #image2").fadeOut(2000); //then this
$("#images #image3").fadeIn(2000);
$("#images #image3").fadeOut(2000); //then this     
$("#images #image4").fadeIn(2000);
$("#images #image4").fadeOut(2000); //then this
$("#images #image1").fadeIn(2000); //then this
```

Here is my index.php file that contains jquery and css if that helps!

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #container {
    width:320px;
    position:relative;
    height:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
        }

      #images {
    height:60px;
    width:320px;
    }

    #images #image1 {
    float:left;
   }

    #images #image2 {
    float:left;
    display:none;

    }
    #images #image3 {
    float:left;
    display:none;

    }
    #images #image4 {
    float:left;
    display:none;



    }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2     /jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/malsup/cycle/master/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//this function will display images from the database
//path is the name of the image
//images is the directory where the images are stored

    $("document").ready(function () {

    $.getJSON('slide.php', function (data) {
            //alert("Data loaded");
      $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $("#images").append('<div class="imageone" id="image1"><img src="images/' +  item.path + '" width="80px" height="60px"/>' + '</div>');
        });

    });

    $.getJSON('f_steptwo.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $("#images").append('<div class="imagetwo" id="image2"><img   src="images/' + item.path + '" width="80" height="60"/>' + '</div>');

    });

});
         $.getJSON('f_stepthree.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $("#images").append('<div class="imagethree" id="image3"><img src="images/' + item.path + '"        width="80" height="60"/>' + '</div>');

            });
        });
        $.getJSON('f_stepfour.php', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $("#images").append('<div class="imagefour" id="image4"><img src="images/' + item.path + '" width="80" height="60"/>' + '</div>');
        }); 

            $("#images #image1").fadeOut(2000);
            $("#images #image2").fadeIn(2000); 
            $("#images #image2").fadeOut(2000);
            $("#images #image3").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#images #image3").fadeOut(2000);     
            $("#images #image4").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#images #image4").fadeOut(2000);

            $("#images #image1").fadeIn(2000);

    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
   <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="images">
   </div>
   </div>
```

And then this entire process need to repeat itself every three seconds or so. Any would be greatly appreciated. This needs to happen when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want an action to take place until the previous one has finished, you can put it in a callback, for your above referenced code it would look like this:

```
$("#image1").fadeIn(2000); //do this first
$("#image2").fadeOut(2000, function () {
    $("#image2").fadeOut(2000); //then this
    $("#image3").fadeIn(2000, function () {
        $("#image3").fadeOut(2000); //then this     
        $("#image4").fadeIn(2000, function () {
            $("#image4").fadeOut(2000, function () { //then this
                $("#image1").fadeIn(2000); //then this 
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Since you want the action to repeat many times putting them in callback would be insane, something like this would be better suited:

```
var elements = ["#image1", "#image2", "#image3", "#image4"];
$(elements.join(',')).hide();
$(elements[0]).show();

var currentElement = 0,
    nextElement = function () {
        $(elements[currentElement]).fadeOut(2000);
        currentElement++;
        if (currentElement === elements.length) {
            currentElement = 0;
        }
        $(elements[currentElement]).fadeIn(2000);
    };
setInterval(nextElement, 3000); // edit this to change the delay between images
```

I assume you're trying to make a slideshow, where one image appears in the same spot as the previous images disappears, in that case instead of doing `float: left` though, I think you might want to do:

```
#images div {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
}
```

This will make it so all the divs are stacked on top of each other, rather than having multiple div's side-by-side.

Also, you do not need to put #images in your selector, id tags are supposed to be unique on a page, so when referencing with id's (using the #) you do not need any other selectors. It should just be $("#image1").

Comment: I'm glad somebody showed this guy how to use variables, lmfao.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this messy callback nesting:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#images #image1").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#images #image2").fadeIn(2000, function(){
            $("#images #image2").fadeOut(2000,function(){
                $("#images #image3").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                    $("#images #image3").fadeOut(2000, function(){
                        $("#images #image4").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                            $("#images #image4").fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                $("#images #image1").fadeIn(2000, function();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}, 16100);
```